# Clone pipelines from one ADF to another

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I need to clone a copy of existing pipelines (pipeline count: 10-20) from one subscription to another subscription's (another ADF). Is there any way to do this activity using Azure Devops?

Answer (score 2):

Option1:

Using [Git Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-clone-data-factory#how-to-clone-a-data-factory), you can publish the data factory to the GIT branch. Connect your new data factory to the same repository and build from the branch. Resources, such as pipelines, datasets, and triggers, will carry through. You can delete the pipelines which are not used.

Option2:

You can manually copy the code (JSON code) of each pipeline, dataset, linked service and use the same code in the new data factory. (Use same names for when creating pipelines/datasets/linked services).